# View [relations.one-two-many.category.index] not found. : laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to show a page in Laravel but its not showing and error is:

> View [relations.one-two-many.category.index] not found.

I am using resource route for it,

controller:

```
   public function index()
   {
       return view('relations.one-two-many.category.index');
   }
```

**error screenshot:** 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a spelling mistake. Your folder name is `one-to-many` but you are using `one-two-many`. Correct the spelling

```
public function index()
   {
       return view('relations.one-to-many.category.index');
   }
```